# logout feedback user in HockeyApp

Tags: ios, swift, hockeyapp

I can't figure out how to log out a user that has been logged in in the [feedback feature](https://hockeyapp.net/features/feedback/) of hockeyapp. I have read through the [documentation](https://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/5.1.2/index.html), but I must have missed it.

The feedback feature is initiated with:

```
BITHockeyManager.shared().feedbackManager.showFeedbackListView()
```

How can I log out a user:

```
func logout() {
    // log out the user from the feedback feature
}
```

Comment: In the `Authentication`'s doc has a function `-cleanupInternalStorage` that will `Removes all previously stored authentication tokens, UDIDs, etc.`. Did you try it

Comment: I have tried that, but it did not remove the user from the feedback feature.